# DRF filter choices by group name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I'm making a media library model, and there are these choices in named groups:

`models.py`

```
class MediaLibrary(models.Model):
    MEDIA_CHOICES = [
        ('Audio', (
                ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
                ('cd', 'CD'),
            )
        ),
        ('Video', (
                ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
                ('dvd', 'DVD'),
            )
        )
    ]
    media_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Media_Choices)
```

If I make a request through DRF, it would return all the objects which match either "Audio" and "Video".

How can I filter the request so that it only returns objects under the "Audio" group. (Or the "Video" group.)

Answer (score 0):

create a model manger and do filter as follows

```
class MediaManager(models.Manager):

    def video_items(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(media_type='Video')

       ---your models here--
       objects = MediaManager()
```

then you can call in your views as `MediaLibrary.objects.video_items()`, similarly filer audio too.

Comment: It returns an empty queryset. :/